# How to Determine Header Level Using Regular Expressions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, markdown

I am using Node.js to read a markdown file for my workplaces orders we take from customers. I am seperating the files into arrays of lines, and performing a check on each line to see what is it (h1, h3, task, etc) but am having lots of trouble getting my RegExps to work correctly. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var filesystem = require('fs');
let content;
let missingItems = [];

filesystem.readFile('orders.md', 'utf8', (err, res) => {
    let content = res;
    let lines = content.split('\n');
    lines.forEach(line => {
        if(line.match(/#{1}/)){
            console.log('Store Name: ', line);
        };
    });
});
```

This code, however returns all h1 AND h3 lines. I saw using RegExp 101 online that the problem is that my RegExp is being matched 3 times for the h3 lines and one time for the h1 lines.

How can I write a regular expression that will not return true for both h1 and h3 lines? I don't understand why this matches 3 times when I'm explicitly saying match {1} ( ONCE )

This is the testing area I've been testing my expressions with and some example text of what I am trying to test against: [RegExp101](https://regex101.com/r/8ewHUk/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if the line contains (at least) one # with that regex, which both lines do.  you could use a negative lookahead:

`^#(?!#)`

`^` means 'start of line', then the literal pound symbol, then the negative lookahead that takes the form of `(?!pattern)`, so we're looking ahead to NOT see another pound symbol.

Much simpler would be to test for the inital # and a following space `\s`:

`^#\s`

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you step me through that RegExp, please? I pasted it into the RegExp101 but it didn't give me a very verbose answer as to what is happening.

Comment: ^ = starting with, ?!# = not follwed by a #

Comment: Thank you so much! Elegant and simple solution.